# Internet Explorer 11 automation VBA Document Empty

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, automation, internet-explorer-11

I am just starting to learn Internet Explorer Automation using VBA and I am facing an issue.

The Document object is empty which prevents me from going further than just loading a page. I have been looking around the net for a solution to this and could not find anything working so here I am, asking for your help.

NB: My VBA level is intermediate

Windows 8.1 pro 64 bit

I wrote an example code

[image: My code and error]

Comment: Have you referenced 'Microsoft HTML Object Library`?

Comment: Yes, I did reference this one and Microsoft Internet Controls as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had a the same issue (nothing in the .document) , with Internet Explorer 11.

I had to add the site to the Compatibility View list (gear, compatibility view, add)

Hopefully this will help someone avoid the time I spent looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. It uses a loop to wait until navigation is complete.

```
Sub NavigateGoogle()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim Googledoc As HTMLDocument

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
        ie.navigate "www.google.com"
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While ie.Busy
    Set Googledoc = ie.document

    Debug.Print Googledoc.all(0).innerHTML

    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```